# How to compute Max function of the following form:

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I knew that in Mathematica, the "Max" function yields the largest element of any of the lists, for example, Max[x,y,z,....].

[image]

How do I implement this function with Mathematica? and what does this function mean?

Comment: [`Maximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html).

Comment: What about the condition, Norm u=1?